# Calling own created java functions without an object?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have 2 classes one of them is **classmain** and another is **myclass** the one contains my own functions. I want to call these functions without creating an object of **myclass**. In C++ creating an *.cpp file and including it to main.cpp is enough to call them. I'm using eclipse with android plug-in.

Thank you for help I forget to say that If I have a function in **myclass** named **Function1**

```
public int function1(){return 1;}
```

I want to call in main something like this:

```
int i = this.function1();
```

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [static methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 2):

you have to set the functions to static, so you can call the functions in this way:

```
MyClass.exampleFunction();
```

the function in your MyClass class looks like:

```
public static void exampleFunction(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `static` keyword for your methods/functions